# Cloud Memorystore redis scale down

Tags: redis, google-cloud-memorystore

Want to know if we scale down Cloud Memorystore Redis standard instance, will it impact to data present inside the cache?

I referred below URL, but didn't find exact information.
https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/scaling-behavior

Answer (score 0):

> Data is preserved during scaling for both Basic and Standard Tier instances.

Quote from [the article that you linked in your question](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/docs/redis/about-scaling-instances#instance_scaling_behavior).